# How to load images from ftp? [iOS]

Tags: ios, nsoperationqueue

There are, for example, 100 JSON files and appropriate 100 images on my ftp server.

1.With loading JSON where are no bug (I hope)

```
NSString *recipesPath = @"ftp://.../recipes/";
NSString *recipeFileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"00001.json", recipeCode];
NSString *recipeFileFullPath = [recipesPath stringByAppendingString:recipeFileName];

NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recipeFileFullPath]];
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

NSError *error = nil;
NSDictionary *recipeDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:responseData options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

2.But images can not be loaded

```
NSString *recipeImageName = @"recipeImages/00001-1.jpg";
NSString *recipeImageFullPath = [recipesPath stringByAppendingString:recipeImageName];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:recipeImageFullPath]];
if (request) {
   NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
   if (responseData) {
       UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:responseData];
   }
}
```

**responseData** nearly always is **nil**.

May be there is the other method?

All this code is in **MyMethod** which I execute in `NSOperationQueue`:

```
operation = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(MyMethod) object:nil];
[operationQueue addOperation:operation];
```

**EDIT:** image sizes are not big - from 50 to 100 kbyte

**EDIT:** can image file extension affect to downloading process?

Comment: Have u tried to log the image's path ?

Comment: yes the path and **request** are correct

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:recipeImageFullPath];
NSData *data = [NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
```

Comment: Have you tried it? If your code is in NSOperationQueue it shouldn't freeze your app.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to test it:

```
NSError *requestError;
NSURLResponse *urlResponse = nil;
NSData *responseData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request  returningResponse:&urlResponse error:&requestError];
/* Return Value
  The downloaded data for the URL request. Returns nil if a connection could not be created or if  the download fails.
*/
 if (responseData == nil) {
// Check for problems
   if (requestError != nil) {
    ...
   }
}
else {
 // Data was received.. continue processing
}
```